# Преобразование и приведение типов .NET Framework

Tags: .net, winforms

Всем привет!
Появилась такая проблема. Делаю форму в Windows Forms для работы с таблицами в БД. Есть словарь dict<string, Object>,
содержащий пары название колонки - тип данных в колонке. Есть массив string[] my_values, куда из TextBox передаются значения, которые я хочу добавить в таблицу, все с типом string соответственно.

Проблема: мне нужно, чтобы в запрос mysql добавлялись значения с уже приведенным типом. Для таких значений я создал List, но вот как эти значения привести и добавить в этот List, я не понимаю. Все способы, которые пробовал, оказались неудачными, может у вас есть идеи?

```
            string str = textBox1.Text;
            my_values = str.Split(new char[] {','});
            string addQuery = $"insert into " + name_of_table + " (";

            for (int i = 0; i < dict.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (dict.ElementAt(i).Key == "To")
                {
                    addQuery = addQuery + "[" + dict.ElementAt(i).Key + "]" + ", ";
                }
                else
                {
                    addQuery = addQuery + dict.ElementAt(i).Key + ", ";
                }
            }
            addQuery = addQuery + dict.ElementAt(dict.Count-1).Key + ") values (";
            for (int i = 0; i < my_values.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                addQuery = addQuery + $"'{my_values[i]}', ";
            }
            addQuery = addQuery + $"'{my_values[my_values.Length - 1]}'" + ")";
```

Comment: И тем не менее - приведите в вопросе способы, какие вы пробовали, прямо вот код покажите. И напишите, какие проблемы с каждым из способов, что не так было.

Comment: Добавил все, что сейчас имею. Но работать оно не будет, так как не приведены типы данных. Словарик dict хранит пары название колонки - тип данных. Но эти типы данных хранятся в формате string. И мои значения, которые я получаю из textBox, хранятся в string. Неявное преобразование тут не сработает, Parse и TryParse тоже, а особо больше то я и не знаю, так как новичок совсем.

Comment: addQuery - строка запроса, которую я пытаюсь составить

Comment: Еще дополнение, главная задача состоит в том, чтобы эта программа работала для любой таблицы в БД.  Отсюда и проблема с типами данных, ведь заранее неизвестно, какие типы в каком столбце будут.